# PHP Script doesn't work on new hosting

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services, upload

This is the code that we're working on. It's supposed to insert values from an android device.

GetGPS.php

```
            include 'init.php';

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            {
               $DefaultId = 0;
               $userid = $_POST['userid'];
               $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
               $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
               $alarm = $_POST['alarm'];
               $address = $_POST['address'];
               $ImageData = $_POST['image_path'];

               $GetOldIdSQL ="SELECT id FROM gpsmessage ORDER BY id ASC";
               $Query = mysqli_query($conn,$GetOldIdSQL);
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){
                $DefaultId = $row['id'];
              }

              $ImagePath = "images/$DefaultId.png";
              $ServerURL = "http://domainurl.com/$ImagePath";


              $InsertSQL = "insert into getdatatable (userid,longitude,latitude,alarm,address,image_path,time_sent) values ('$userid','$longitude','$latitude','$alarm','$address','$ServerURL',NOW())";
            mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL);

              if(file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData))){
               echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
              }
              mysqli_close($conn);
              }
            else{
            echo "Not Uploaded";
            }

            ?>
```

So we have 2 web hosts. Let's call them A and B.

A is our old and outdated host but it works in inserting data from any Android version.

B is our new host but the code doesn't work when using Android version 5 or less. and shows undefined index in error page. It works fine with Android version 6 and up and no errors showing. This also has the updated functions for my project.

```
        [22-Mar-2018 09:33:44 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userid in /home/username/public_html/func/GetGPS.php on line 11
        [22-Mar-2018 09:33:44 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: longitude in /home/username/public_html/func/GetGPS.php on line 12
        [22-Mar-2018 09:33:44 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: latitude in /home/username/public_html/func/GetGPS.php on line 13
        [22-Mar-2018 09:33:44 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alarm in /home/username/public_html/func/GetGPS.php on line 14
        [22-Mar-2018 09:33:44 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: address in /home/username/public_html/func/GetGPS.php on line 15
```

I've tried migrating files from A Hosting to B Hosting but it doesn't work.  Is it a problem in the code, device or in the hosting? Or it's lacking permission from android application. We haven't changed anything in configs from both hosting.

tldr ver:

Hosting A = 
Any android version works with no empty fields

Hosting B = 
ID 25 is when Android v5 or below is used. ID 24 is when Android v6 and up is used

**Attached here is a sample query from B Hosting [Sample Query Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ4m0.png)**

Thank you.

*If Hosting A works, why not just use it?*

It's only a free hosting/service so there's limited resource we can use. Processes already hit the red bar so we spend for Hosting B.

Comment: Have you change the post URL at android side? As you have change hosting so you have to change the URL too as per new hosting

Comment: Yes, we have already changed the URL in the android side.